# Not able to downgrade the deploy to container

Tags: jenkins, devops

[image]I have an issue with deploy to container plugins v 1.15 so I have decided to remove the current version and downloaded the V1.13 manually and copied the .hpi to /var/lib/Jenkins folder and restarted the Jenkins many times and specific dependencies with specific versions installed manually all the versions look ok but deploy to container plugin not installing that I don't see any deploy folder and deploy.jpi file.

Please suggest me is there anything I missing?

Comment: Can you add more information on your problem. What are you trying to get ? is it upgrading the docker plugin in jenkins ? how is you jenkins installed as container or k8s, old fashion installation ? is it hapening on current running jenkins or during a clean installation ?

Comment: Hi Mickey, Thanks I have installed Jenkins on a cloud server and I have generated build with war file and wanted to deploy to tomcat. when I trying to deploy I keep getting the error and I found that some solution related to the same issue that they recommend me to downgrade the Deploy to container plugin on Jenkins. PFA able screenshot